# Linear system - causal and memoryless system (integral)

Tags: homework, system

\$T{(x(t))} = \int _{-\infty }^{+\infty }sin\left(t+\tau \right)x\left(\tau \right)d\tau\$

Is this system causal or not?  Is it memoryless or not?

At first I thought it was not causal and with memory since the boundaries are from \$-\infty\$ to \$+\infty\$.

I later realized that since the boundary does not depend on \$t\$ then it is not correct to do it that way.

I guess it means that the system is causal and memoryless, since it does not have dependence on \$t\$ at integral.

How do I show it?

If this helps:

The system is linear, not time invariant, not stable (according to what I managed to find,) regarding invertible I guess it is not, but could not prove it. My intuition says it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let \$x(t)=\delta(t)\$. The output (the impulse response) is \$h(t) = \sin(t)\$, which is not strictly zero for \$t<0\$. Therefore, the system is not causal. A non-causal system is also not memoryless.

The output signal for \$x(t)=\delta(t-2\pi)\$ is also \$\sin(t)\$. Since the inputs \$\delta(t)\$ and \$\delta(t-2\pi)\$ produce the same output, the system is not invertible.